# Fazer consulta entre duas tabelas mesmo com o count retornando 0

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu estou tentando fazer uma consulta que irá unir algumas tabelas no meu banco de dados, utilizando um join. As tabelas são as seguintes:

Tabela 1 -  RESULTADOS_SIGLAS

| ID_RESULTADO | RESULTADO | SIGLA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | RESULTADO 1 | RES1 |
| 2 | RESULTADO 2 | RES2 |
| 3 | RESULTADO 3 | RES3 |

Tabela 2 - RESULTADOS FINAIS

| ID_RES_FINAL | ID_TURMA | ID_ALUNO | ID_RESULTADO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 123 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 321 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 444 | 2 |

O que eu preciso é buscar a quantidade de alunos que possuem determinado resultado e as informações daquele resultado (O resultado em si e a Sigla dele), ex: Buscar todos os alunos da turma 3 que possuam o resultado 1.

Então, na minha cabeça, eu deveria fazer a consulta da seguinte maneira:

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(RESULTADOS_FINAIS.ID_ALUNO) AS QUANTIDADE, 
  RESULTADOS_SIGLAS.RESULTADO,
  RESULTADOS_SIGLAS.SIGLA
FROM RESULTADOS_SIGLAS 
  INNER JOIN RESULTADOS_FINAIS on RESULTADOS_SIGLAS.ID_RESULTADO = RESULTADOS_FINAIS.ID_RESULTADO
WHERE RESULTADOS_FINAIS.ID_TURMA = 3
  AND RESULTADOS_FINAIS.ID_RESULTADO = 1
```

O que eu queria que ele me retornasse, nessa situação hipotética era:

| QUANTIDADE | RESULTADO | SIGLA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | RESULTADO 1 | RES1 |

Mas ele acabou me retornando o seguinte:

| QUANTIDADE | RESULTADO | SIGLA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NULL | NULL |

Alguém poderia me ajudar nesta consulta? Desde já, agradeço bastante!

Eu preciso que mesmo que a quantidade seja 0, ele me retorne o resultado e a sigla. Nesse caso eu teria que fazer essas consultas separadas no banco e depois controlar elas por um laço for?

Comment: Tem certeza que este resultado informado por você está ocorrendo? Criei um schema parecido com este e o resultado saiu conforme o esperado: (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4ad81/1/0)

Comment: me parece muito estranho quantidade retornar zero e ter um resultado/sigla, se o count foi zero é pq não encontrou ninguém

Comment: Marcos, agora foi estranho. Pra mim ele retorna a quantidade como 0 e os outros valores como null mesmo...